# Горизонтальное непрерывное движения картинок слева на право

Tags: html, css, css-animation

[image: слайдер]
Не знаю как сделать непрерывный цикл что бы картинки двигались с левой стороны в правую, можно ли это реализовать через css?

```css
 .img-partners {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
   
 }
```

```html
 <div class="partners container-fluid">
        <div class="img-partners">
            <img class="partners-img" src="./assets/img/partners/logo.svg" alt=""/>
            <img class="partners-img" src="./assets/img/partners/logo-1.svg" alt=""/>
            <img class="partners-img" src="./assets/img/partners/logo-2.svg" alt=""/>
            <img class="partners-img" src="./assets/img/partners/logo-3.svg" alt=""/>
            <img class="partners-img" src="./assets/img/partners/logo-4.svg" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/studiojvla/pen/qVbQqW - вот готовый пример, вы всегда проверяйте, есть ли готовый код для этого

Comment: по сути почти все слайдеры на CSS одинаковые по производительности